# Copying local files to RDS

Tags: rds, data-pump

How do I copy/upload my dump files from local system to RDS instance. The documentation talks about creating a dump from sample table to data_pump_dir and copying the same to another file. However I could no find out how to get dump I have locally to move to data_pump_dir space such that I can import the data from the uploaded file.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the link I found which clearly says copying dump file is not supported on RDS.

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=415864